# Setting UINavigationBar tint color in monotouch for iOS7

Tags: xamarin.ios, ios7, uinavigationbar, xcode5

I just updated to latest Xamarin.iOS 4.10.0 and xCode5 for developing my app for iOS7.
In iOS7 now the tint color of the `UINavigationBar` is not set with Tint color but with BarTintColor. so the following :

```
NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.Red;
```

doesn't do anything for ios7 (in ios6 it does change the color the top bar).

How can I change the `UINAvigationBar` color using monotouch for iOS7? I even tried to change via the xCode5, but it seems to not work as well

Comment: looks like the answer is in the question: "but with BarTintColor"

Comment: From some reason when I got to my UINavigationController and write the following :  NavigationBar.BarTintColor doesn't compile, it seems that it doesn't recognise this property. I'm  using Xamarin.iOS 4.0.10 .
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 2):

From [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/transitionguide/Bars.html):

> iOS7: Use tintColor to tint bar button items. 
>   Use barTintColor to tint the bar background.
>
> iOS6: Use tintColor to tint the bar background.

Which translate in monotouch to: `TintColor` and `BarTintColor`

Comment: I dont have BarTinColor when I use monotouch. I updated to the latest version of from the Xamarine website and working with xCode5. 
That's very wired. wich version r u using?

Comment: `BarTintColor` is a property of `UINavigationBar`. 4.0.10 is the version of Xamarin.Studio. What's the version of Xamarin.iOS ? (Xamarin Studio > About Xamarin Studio > Show Details). You need Xamarin.iOS >= 7.0